# How can I impute values to outlier cells based on groups?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe with some values

```
#| X | Y | Value1 | Value2 |
---------------------------
1| 2 | 4 |   10   |   3    |
2| 2 | 4 |    3   |   2    |
3| 2 | 4 |    1   |   4    |
4| 4 | 5 |    5   |   20   |
5| 4 | 5 |    3   |   2    |
6| 5 | 6 |    1   |   2    |
7| 4 | 5 |    4   |   3    |
----------------------------
```

The goal is to impute values for similar groups ( based on X, Y values)  for columns Value1 and Value2.

e.g. X=2,Y=4 has values 1, 3, 10 for Value 1. Using median imputation I would like to replace the 10 by 3, as 3 is the median. Similarly, for X=4, Y=5 the values are 2, 3, 20 for Value2 column. I would like to replace the 20 with the median 3.

Note: 10 and 20 are being treated as outliers here.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: How we determine the cut of outlier ~

Comment: @ansev the expected output would be for row 1, value 1  = 3  as (1, 3, 10) has median 3 and for row 4 value 2 =3 as (2, 3, 20) has also median 3.

Comment: @BEN_YO this is just an example table, I used zscore normalization with threshold 3 to  check for the outliers.

Comment: How come (1,3,10) for row 1?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov As I am wanting to group by columns X and Y. 
For (X=2, Y=4) we get (1,3, 10) in the dataframe. Here the median is 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following answer from n1k31t4 in: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37717/imputation-missing-values-other-than-using-mean-median-in-python
I was able to solve my problem.

```
df[col]=df.groupby(['X', 'Y'])[col].transform(lambda x: x.median() if (np.abs(x)>3).any() else x)
```