# median imputation by groups in pandas (handling group medians that are NaN)

Tags: pandas, group-by, imputation

I have the following DataFrame train:

```
train = {'NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE': {5: 'Secondary / secondary special',
  6: 'Higher education',
  7: 'Higher education',
  8: 'Secondary / secondary special',
  9: 'Secondary / secondary special',
  10: 'Higher education',
  11: 'Secondary / secondary special',
  12: 'Secondary / secondary special',
  13: 'Secondary / secondary special',
  14: 'Secondary / secondary special'},
 'OCCUPATION_TYPE': {5: 'Laborers',
  6: 'Accountants',
  7: 'Managers',
  8: nan,
  9: 'Laborers',
  10: 'Core staff',
  11: nan,
  12: 'Laborers',
  13: 'Drivers',
  14: 'Laborers'},
 'AGE_GROUP': {5: '45-60',
  6: '21-45',
  7: '45-60',
  8: '45-60',
  9: '21-45',
  10: '21-45',
  11: '45-60',
  12: '21-45',
  13: '21-45',
  14: '21-45'},
 'DAYS_EMPLOYED': {5: -1588.0,
  6: -3130.0,
  7: -449.0,
  8: nan,
  9: -2019.0,
  10: -679.0,
  11: nan,
  12: -2717.0,
  13: -3028.0,
  14: -203.0},
 'DAYS_EMPLOYED_ANOM': {5: False,
  6: False,
  7: False,
  8: True,
  9: False,
  10: False,
  11: True,
  12: False,
  13: False,
  14: False},
 'DAYS_LAST_PHONE_CHANGE': {5: -2536.0,
  6: -1562.0,
  7: -1070.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: -1673.0,
  10: -844.0,
  11: -2396.0,
  12: -2370.0,
  13: -4.0,
  14: -188.0}}
```

I have a few NaN in the column DAYS_EMPLOYED. They are flagged as "True" in the column DAYS_EMPLOYED_ANOM.
I want to impute these NaN using the median of DAYS_EMPLOYED by the following group of columns : NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE, OCCUPATION_TYPE and AGE_GROUP

I believe this can be done in a few lines in pandas but I could not figure it out. I have tried to apply the following code that I found in an example of mean imputation for a Series, but the NaN values do not get imputed.

```
fill_median = lambda g: g.fillna(g.median())
train.loc[train['DAYS_EMPLOYED_ANOM'] == True,'DAYS_EMPLOYED'] = train.groupby(['NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE', 'OCCUPATION_TYPE', 'AGE_GROUP'])['DAYS_EMPLOYED'].apply(fill_median)`
```

I also tried to apply the code from this post without success:
[How can I impute values to outlier cells based on groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64124914/how-can-i-impute-values-to-outlier-cells-based-on-groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
train['DAYS_EMPLOYED'] =  (train.groupby(['NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE', 'OCCUPATION_TYPE', 'AGE_GROUP'],
                                         dropna=False)
                                ['DAYS_EMPLOYED']
                                .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
                          )
```

However, note that this will not work on your particular dataset as you need to have at least one non NaN value per group to be able to calculate the median.

You could use the population median instead:

```
train['DAYS_EMPLOYED'] =  (train.groupby(['NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE', 'OCCUPATION_TYPE', 'AGE_GROUP'],
                                         dropna=False)
                                ['DAYS_EMPLOYED']
                                .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(train['DAYS_EMPLOYED'].median()))
                          )
```

Here is an hybrid approach to try calculating the group median and otherwise fall back to population one:

```
def median(s):
    m = s.median()
    if np.isnan(m):
        m = train['DAYS_EMPLOYED'].median()
    return m

train['DAYS_EMPLOYED'] =  (train.groupby(['NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE', 'OCCUPATION_TYPE', 'AGE_GROUP'],
                                         dropna=False
                                        )
                                ['DAYS_EMPLOYED'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(median(s)))
                          )
```

Comment: Thanks mozway ! I had way too many NaN in the column OCCUPATION_TYPE to use it to compute a group median, if I remove it it works fine. And I will definitely use your hybrid function.

Comment: Hi @mozway, I have been trying to apply your hybrid method with mode instead of median to impute categorical data. But it looks like np.isnan cannot handle some modes of the groups as input, i get the following error:
`TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Here are the modes of the different groups as represented in the output of jupyter:
Stone, NaN, []         I can make a new post with a reproducible example if it helps

Comment: if you want to give a look :) 
[new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68957043/mode-imputation-by-groups-in-pandas-handling-group-modes-that-are-nan-or)