# mode imputation by groups in pandas (handling group modes that are NaN)

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, nan, categorical-data, imputation

I have a categorical column "WALLSMATERIAL_MODE" containing NaN that I want to impute using the mode by the following groups ['NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE', 'AGE_GROUP']:

```
    NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE             AGE_GROUP   WALLSMATERIAL_MODE
20  Secondary / secondary special   45-60       Stone, brick
21  Secondary / secondary special   21-45       NaN
22  Secondary / secondary special   21-45       Panel
23  Secondary / secondary special   60-70       Mixed
24  Secondary / secondary special   21-45       Panel
25  Secondary / secondary special   45-60       Stone, brick
26  Secondary / secondary special   45-60       Wooden
27  Secondary / secondary special   21-45       NaN
28  Higher education                21-45       NaN
29  Higher education                21-45       Panel
```

---

Code for reproducibility

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE': {20: 'Secondary / secondary special',
  21: 'Secondary / secondary special',
  22: 'Secondary / secondary special',
  23: 'Secondary / secondary special',
  24: 'Secondary / secondary special',
  25: 'Secondary / secondary special',
  26: 'Secondary / secondary special',
  27: 'Secondary / secondary special',
  28: 'Higher education',
  29: 'Higher education'},
 'AGE_GROUP': {20: '45-60',
  21: '21-45',
  22: '21-45',
  23: '60-70',
  24: '21-45',
  25: '45-60',
  26: '45-60',
  27: '21-45',
  28: '21-45',
  29: '21-45'},
 'WALLSMATERIAL_MODE': {20: 'Stone, brick',
  21: np.nan,
  22: 'Panel',
  23: 'Mixed',
  24: 'Panel',
  25: 'Stone, brick',
  26: 'Wooden',
  27: np.nan,
  28: np.nan,
  29: 'Panel'}})
```

I tried adapting the following function from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68455028/median-imputation-by-groups-in-pandas-handling-group-medians-that-are-nan) that works for median imputation and handles group medians that are NaN

IN:

```
def mode(s):
    if pd.isnull(s.mode()):
        return df['WALLSMATERIAL_MODE'].mode()
    return s.mode()
        
df['WALLSMATERIAL_MODE'] = df['WALLSMATERIAL_MODE'].groupby([df['NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE'], df['AGE_GROUP']], dropna=False).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(mode(x)))
```

OUT: The following error is raised when pd.isnull is called

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

I do not understand, I have tried to apply pd.isnull on all the group modes, and it does not raise this error. See the group modes below

IN:

```
df['WALLSMATERIAL_MODE'].groupby([df['NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE'], df['AGE_GROUP']]).agg(pd.Series.mode).to_dict()
```

OUT:

```
{('Higher education', '60-70'): nan,
 ('Higher education', '45-60'): nan,
 ('Higher education', '21-45'): 'Panel',
 ('Higher education', '0-21'): nan,
 ('Secondary / secondary special', '60-70'): 'Mixed',
 ('Secondary / secondary special', '45-60'): 'Stone, brick',
 ('Secondary / secondary special', '21-45'): 'Panel',
 ('Secondary / secondary special', '0-21'): nan}
```

If anyone can tell where the mistake is or if there is an effective way to impute this column by groups, I will be thankful !

Comment: The main difference between the post with `median` (the link provided) and using `mode`, is that `mode` return a `Series` while `median` return a single value. hence doing `if ...s.mode()` return the common value error of using `if` with a Series. A quick fix would be in your function every time you use `mode`, use `...mode().iloc[0]`

Comment: Thanks Ben, I tried with  `pd.isnull(s.mode().iloc[0])`  but I get the following error `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code seems to do the trick using try except. I'd rather I avoided using try except but I could not figure out a cleaner way.

```
def mode_cats(s):
        try:
            if pd.isnull(s.mode().any()): # check if the mode of the subgroup is NaN or contains NaN 
                                          # (mode() may indeed return a list of several modes)
                m = app_train_dash['WALLSMATERIAL_MODE'].mode().iloc[0] # returns the mode of the column
            else:
                m = s.mode().iloc[0]  # returns the mode of the subgroup
            return m
        except IndexError: # mode returns an empty series if the subgroup consists of a single NaN value
                           # this causes s.mode().iloc[0] to raise an index error
            return app_train_dash['WALLSMATERIAL_MODE'].mode().iloc[0]
```

As @Ben.T pointed out, I had to use `.iloc[0]` with `.mode()`
But then I get `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds` when the `.mode().iloc[0]` has an empty array as input.
Traceback of the error:

1. mode() is called on a subgroup of one row with value = NaN. .mode() returns an empty array for this subgroup of a single NaN
2. pd.isnull is called on the passed empty array and returns an empty array
3. Calling .iloc[0] on an empty array raises the index error